# AÑADIR MARCADORES MAPA LEAFLET

Tags: javascript, laravel, map, leaflet

No se como añadir mas marcadores a mi mapa de leaflet con la funcion de geocoding que me convierte direcciones a coordenadas, ya trate de agregar ciclos for pero no me loes muestra, aqui el codigo inicial:

```
<div id="map"></div>



 var map = L.map('map').setView([17.0812861,-96.805772], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}).addTo(map);

var query_addr = "Prolongación de Xicoténcatl 1031, 68120 , MX";

const provider = new window.GeoSearch.OpenStreetMapProvider()
var query_promise = provider.search({
  query: query_addr
});


query_promise.then(value => {
  for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    // Success!
    var x_coor = value[i].x;
    var y_coor = value[i].y;
    var label = value[i].label;
    var marker = L.marker([y_coor, x_coor]).addTo(map) 
    marker.bindPopup("<b>Found location</b><br>" + label).openPopup();     };
}, reason => {
  console.log(reason); 
});
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor no escribas en mayusculas porque parece que estas gritando

Comment: ¿y esto qué tiene que ver con Laravel?